# Delete one column on the criteria of another SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql

One attribute in a table became corrupted after a certain point in a table of mine.  I want to  delete every pat_coun attribute if it has an ID that **begins** with 11 (number, not text).  So I don't want to get rid of any of the records in the database, just clear out the attribute pat_coun if it's ID begins with 11

```
DELETE pat_coun from myTable
WHERE id %11
```

Just want to make sure this is right before I go deleting stuff.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To clear out an attribute, do **NOT** use the `DELETE` function! That **deletes** a row from your table!

You need to use `UPDATE` instead:

```
UPDATE myTable
SET pat_coun = NULL
WHERE id LIKE '11%'
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to delete a record (a row) you can use

```
DELETE FROM myTable
WHERE condition
```

If you just want to "clear" a particular column you should use

```
UPDATE myTable
SET pat_coun = 0 // or NULL or whatever you please
WHERE condition
```

For condition IMHO you should convert your number to string and check like this

```
WHERE CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), pat_coun) LIKE '11%'
```

Comment: what advantage does that offer?

Comment: @DarrinCecil: simply I was not sure syntax you used was correct (I cannot test it now) :)

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
update myTable
set pat_coun = null
where id like '11%'
```